# Test whether the elements in two ranges are equal in C# using a lambda and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a LINQ or C# method that helps to test whether the elements in two ranges are equal in C# using a lambda and LINQ.

In fact, I have 2 array of objects and I want to check if a property is the same on both array objects.

In C++, there's std::equal that can used with a lambda (example inspired from https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/)

```
// equal algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::equal
#include <vector>       // std::vector

bool mypredicate (int i, int j) {
  return (i==j);
}

int main () {
  int myints[] = {20,40,60,80,100};               //   myints: 20 40 60 80 100
  std::vector<int>myvector (myints,myints+5);     // myvector: 20 40 60 80 100

  myvector[3]=81;                                 // myvector: 20 40 60 81 100

  // using predicate comparison:
  if ( std::equal (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myints, [](int i, int j){ return i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0; }) )
    std::cout << "The contents of both sequences are equal.\n";
  else
    std::cout << "The contents of both sequences differ.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: another C++ example that comes close to what I am trying to do:

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::equal
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string
#include <vector>       // std::vector

using namespace std;

struct Device
{
    Device(string id) : id(id) {}
    string id;
};

int main () {
  Device mydevices[] = {Device("A1"), Device("A2")};
  std::vector<Device> myvector(mydevices,mydevices+2);

  mydevices[1].id = "B1";

  // using predicate comparison:
  if ( std::equal (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), mydevices, [](Device i, Device j){ return i.id == j.id; }) )
    std::cout << "The contents of both sequences are equal.\n";
  else
    std::cout << "The contents of both sequences differ.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to compare a property of each element, or the entire element? Your sample code is using ints which don't have properties, so it's a little unclear, but your question mentions comparing elements *and* comparing properties. Also: Are you using arrays or lists? (there are different solutions depending on which).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I use objects and I want to compare the properties of each element of the two arrays (they have the same length), the example is to illustrate what already exists in C++.

Comment: So, why don't you post what you're actually working with instead of C++ code that is not related to what you're asking? So you don't get answers that cannot address a problem that is not really shown in the question.

Comment: Does the type of the elements of the array implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` or `IEquatable<T>` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Like in the new C++ example I have just added, my objects have a string property, and I want to check if that property is the same for all the elements having the same index in both arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your edited question:

It appears that you have arrays of a type which has a property that you want to compare, ignoring other properties.

Furthermore, the type of the property that you want to compare implements `IEquals<T>` and `GetHashCode()` (because it's a `string`).

In this case, you can compare the two arrays like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TestClass[] a1 = { new ("1", 1), new ("2", 2), new ("3", 3) };
        TestClass[] a2 = { new ("1", 2), new ("2", 3), new ("3", 4) };

        bool propertiesAreEqual = 
            a1.Select(element => element.PropertyToCompare)
            .SequenceEqual(
                a2.Select(element => element.PropertyToCompare));

        Console.WriteLine(propertiesAreEqual); // True
    }
}

record TestClass(string PropertyToCompare, int SomeOtherProperty);
```

Try it in DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NR6bog

Note: I'm just using `record` for brevity. This also works with a normal class, of course.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted to see, so in C# we have to use a "map" operation than use SequenceEqual on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0):

```
int[] myints = {20,40,60,20,40};
IEnumerable<int> range1 = myints.Take(2);
IEnumerable<int> range2 = myints.Skip(3);
bool equalRanges = range1.SequenceEqual(range2); // true
```

If you need to compare object properties you have multiple options:

1. override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and use the code above
2. implement `IEquatable<YourObjectType>` and use the code above
3. implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<YourObjectType>` and use an instance of it as parameter for `SequenceEqual` and the code above
4. Use a different LINQ query like this:

   ```
   YourObjectType[] myobjects = {...};
   IEnumerable<YourObjectType> range1 = myobjects.Take(2);
   IEnumerable<YourObjectType> range2 = myobjects.Skip(3);
   bool equalRanges = range1.Zip(range2, (x1, x2) => AreEqual(x1, x2)).All(b => b);
   ```

(where `AreEqual` is a method that compares the properties, you could do this inline as well)

Comment: The example I posted is to illustrate std::equal. I need to compare objects properties.

Comment: Can you please see my 2nd C++ example. Thanks

Comment: @Aminos: can you decribe what you need in words, (c#)code and with sample data and an expected result instead of with C++? I'm not a C++ developer and stackoverflow is also not a"translation-service" ;-)

Comment: my objects have a string property, and I want to check if that property is the same for all the elements having the same index in both arrays in an elegant way.

Comment: @Aminos well i have shown that in my editied answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1)))) to create an IEnumerable of tuples. With [`All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-6.0) you can check whether all of this tuples fulfill a condition:

```
Device[] devices1 = {new Device("A1"), new Device("A2")};
Device[] devices2 = {new Device("A1"), new Device("A2")};

if(devices1.Zip(devices2).All(x => x.Item1.ID == x.Item2.ID))
{
    Console.WriteLine("devices1 and devices2 IDs are the same");
}
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FIFOYP